# NUnit how to detect dependencies between tests?

Tags: .net, nunit

I have started work with one project and I figured out that some of Unit tests relies on the fact that another one have been run before it. Is there any way to detect this kind of tests without running them all manually? There are couple of thousands of tests in this project and it isn't most interesting thing to do I have.

Comment: What do you mean that some relies on other ? Share the same data ?

Comment: "......some of Unit tests relies on the fact that another one have been run before it." In that case what you have are integration tests, not unit tests. True unit tests can run in any order; they have no dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid NUnit has nothing to help with the problem, although I've often thought about some feature that would **detect** dependencies. That would be for the future, though.

For now, here's the approach I follow. I'm assuming the use of the console runner and NUnit 3.x.

1. Add the argument `--workers=0` to the command-line and verify that the problem still exists. That setting forces all tests to run sequentially, ruling out the possibility that the problem is due to parallel execution, which would be a different matter.
2. Use the `--where` option to select some portion of the test fixtures. Selecting about half is best, if you can do that. If necessary, use temporary namespace changes to make it easier.
3. If the problem disappeared, run the other half of the tests.
4. At this point, if you're lucky, you have narrowed down the problem to half the tests. Go back to step 2, subdividing the half that exhibits the problem. Continue with this approach, a variation of binary search, until you have one fixture to work with. At that point, you should be able to discover the problem by inspection or debugging.
5. In step 4, I said "if you're lucky". If you are particularly unlucky, the problem may be across fixtures. This can happen if fixtures share some sort of state, particularly when using the file system. In that case, you have to try a different partition of the tests until the problem turns up.

This is a fairly tedious process and can take a while. It's sometimes easier to just go through all the tests looking for opportunities for dependency and removing them. Ideally, no test code should set state of the object or externally. Anything doing that is suspect.

Answer (score 0):

If test cases prerequiste is defined in the file it will be easy to identify. Else you need to go with trial and error method to identify this information. You can organize your test after that with Test Initialize and Test Cleanup.

Comment: There aren't any clues, but maybe there is some test runner, or nUnit setting that allow me run every test in separate AppDomain with full initialization. I accept that it probably will take hours to finish it but It can save me a lot more work.